# How can I display the equivalent value of the alphabet adding each other?

Tags: java

How can I display the equivalent value of the alphabet adding each other?

My input is abc so the output should be 6 since:

a = 1

b = 2

c = 3

but I want to display the numbers adding each other

ex.

1+2+3 = 6

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String []args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Alphabet");

    String input = s.nextLine();

    char[] charArray = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    int sum = 0;

    for (char c : charArray) {

        sum += (int)c-96;

    }

    System.out.println(sum);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `StringBuilder` to keep track of the values as in :

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Alphabet");

    String input = s.nextLine();

    char[] charArray = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    int sum = 0;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    int i = 1;
    for (char c : charArray) {

        sum += (int) c - 96;
        builder.append((int) c - 96);

        if(i != charArray.length)
            builder.append(" + ");
        else if(i == charArray.length)
            builder.append(" = ");

        i++;
    }
    builder.append(sum);
    System.out.println(builder);

}
```